# Can I use two different signatures for the same account in playStore?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to use a different **keystore** to publish my new Android application on the **Playstore**, one different than the one I used to publish the first application. In fact, I already deliver the application to clients with the new certificate and I must use this certificate now, in order to update it via the store.

I would like to know if I should create another account for this application or can I publish with the same account but with a different signature?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different keystore to publish different apps. there is no problem with that. But to update existing apps you must use the previous keystore

Comment: I would like to keep the old application with existing keystore. and i  would like to use a new keystore and to update my new application. is it possible with the some count.

Comment: may I ask the reason of downvoting.. if i am wrong can you pls correct me?

Comment: @Zizou do you exactly want? you can publish the app with a different package name. what is the problem here?

Comment: when i creat a new project, and i lodded my new application's apk with my new keystore. I have already a problem i can't access to price and disponibility error code -(32600). i tried all suggestion. to reboot to use others browser. I don't kwo what to do.